# Prove $\frac{\cos^3{x}-\sin^3{x}}{\cos{x}-\sin{x}} =1+\frac{1}{2} \sin{2x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Prove

$$\frac{\cos^3{x}-\sin^3{x}}{\cos{x}-\sin{x}} =1+\frac{1}{2} \sin{2x}$$

How do I start :( which identity do I use?

Comment: Use the fact $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: use the identity:

$(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

---

Solution follows:

We have 
$\cos^3 x -\sin^3 x =(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos^2 x +\cos x\sin x +\sin^2 x )$.

So:

$$\eqalign{{
\cos^3 x -\sin^3 x\over \cos x-\sin x}&= 
{(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos^2 x +\cos x\sin x +\sin^2 x )\over (\cos x-\sin x)}\cr
&=1+\cos x\sin x\cr
&=1+\textstyle{1\over2}\sin 2x.}
$$

(The last equality used the trigonometric identity $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$.)

---

As @Dilip  Sarwate points out in the comment below, the above does not hold when $\cos x=\sin x$. In this case, ${
\cos^3 x -\sin^3 x\over \cos x-\sin x}$ is not defined.  Of course, whenever  ${
\cos^3 x -\sin^3 x\over \cos x-\sin x}$ is defined, it is equal to $1+{1\over2}\sin 2x$.

Comment: Its 1+\cos(x)\sin(x)

Comment: +1 But perhaps a note could be added as to what happens when $x = \pi/4$, say, and we cannot cancel $\cos x - \sin x$ from numerator and denominator?

Comment: $f(x)={\cos^3 x-\sin^3 x\over\cos x-\sin x}$ is not defined at $x=n\pi+\pi/4,n\in\mathbb Z$ and thus is not continuous at all $x\in\mathbb R$, while a related function $$g(x)=\begin{cases}{
\cos^3 x -\sin^3 x\over \cos x-\sin x},&x\neq n\pi+\pi/4,\\\frac{3}{2},&x=n\pi+\pi/4,\end{cases}$$ is continuous at all $x\in\mathbb R$ and equals $1 + \frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.